# PyQt signal-slots and OS events

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, pyinotify

My PyQt application needs to learn about certain OS events (such as Unix Signals, or Filesystem events). For example, say myReaper (a unix process) will execute myProvider (another Unix process) and waits for for its child to exit. myReaper then want to communicate the exit status to myQtApp.

1. One solution would be for myReaper to (unix) signal myQtApp. But seems like I'd need to go through a socketpair or similar workarounds, see  https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/unix-signals.html
2. Another solution would be for myReaper to write status to a file and myQtApp wakes up via PyInotify (FS events) and read the content. I think this would also suffer from similar issues as unix signals.
3. Another solution would be to use QTimer to wake up every so often and check a file. A polling based system but with minimal plumbing to OS events.

Has anyone dealt with this type of problem? What do you recommend?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use an IPC ?, for example dbus.

Comment: Can you elaborate please ... a general overview, I think you mean myReaper would inject a message on to the bus, and myQtApp would periodically check to see if there is a message ? Is that correct ? However if dbus is to asynchronously inform the subscriber (myQtApp), then I think we are back at Qt does not like to share. Correct me if incorrect.

Comment: I could give you an example if you provide a simple **but workable** example of myReaper and myQtApp.

Comment: From what I understand you is that an application (myQtApp) knows if another application (myReaper) is running or not, and if myReaper starts or ends when myQtApp is executed then also be notified of it. Am I correct?

Comment: Here is the process call flow. myQtApp ---> xterm ---> reaper ---> myProvider. The challenge is that xterm returns immediately (basically saying I ran ok, I don't know about the rest of the story). So myQtApp does some magic and figures out PID of reaper and myProvider. So now problem has reduced to, myQtApp wants to learn when myProvider has exited and what was the exist code. In the meantime, myQtApp is running around its event loop managing its internal affairs. And myProvider is executing on its own. Given that, how can myQtApp find out if myProvider has existed and what was the exit code.